# Using select tags with the same name

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm cloning with JQuery a `select` tag to let the user to fill some more fields:

original HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="theName">
        <option value="any">Any</option>
        ...
    </select>
</form>
```

transformed HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="theName">
        <option value="any">Any</option>
        ...
    </select>
    <select name="theName">
        <option value="other">Other</option>
        ...
    </select>
</form>
```

The problem is that I'm getting only the second parameter in `$_POST['theName']`.

Should I rename all new `select` tags names?

Comment: yes you should rename them if you want to get them seperately in `$_POST`. if problem is that with you jquery applied on the select by name transform it to class name and apply same class to you each select box

Comment: you have to create an array of the name <select name="theName[]">

Comment: If they are options form the same select why don't you add more option??

Comment: @oBo - Thanks. It works. Do you want to put it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an array of the name like this

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="theName[]">
        <option value="any">Any</option>
        ...
    </select>
    <select name="theName[]">
        <option value="other">Other</option>
        ...
    </select>
</form>
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

use the html as

```
<select name="theName[]">
```

and in your `$_POST['theName']` you will get the all select box value as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute name is not unique but in this case you will have an error because jquery will try to store all the values in one single variable re-assigning  the value each time.

solution 1 :change the name
solution 2 :store your result in one list

Answer (score 0):

try different names for both select boxes